# Cannot connect to my website using external IP using apache tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a connection problem with my jsp website. It is fine and work if I use http://localhost:8080/examples/... But when I changed it to my current IP address, then it doesn't work. At first, I think it is the router problem, so I adjust the settings of router, but even after I removed the router, it still does not work.

I have searched this question before and I have already changed the server.xml (add address="0.0.0.0" useIPVHosts="true") into

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" address="0.0.0.0" useIPVHosts="true" />
```

I have also tried to close the firewall. But it still doesn't work.
I am using apache tomcat 9.0.0.M1 and Windows 10.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to access it using the URI like http://IP_Address:port/ProjectName ?

Comment: Yes. I cannot access through this link with my IP address, just replacing localhost...Do I need to do any extra setting in my PC, thanks!

Comment: It would be great if you can share portion of logs at $CATALINA_HOME/logs/.

Comment: I find that may be it is still the problem of my router. As I use the online open port check, I find that the Port 8080 is closed, how can I open it or what is wrong with that? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the router webpage. I find that the WAN IP address is a private address? I just have one router. How to deal with that? Thanks.

Step 3: Pay attention to the WAN IP address in status page

If step 1 and 2 confirmed no problem, but you still fails to access the server remotely. Please check the WAN IP address on the status page of the router, and verify it’s a public IP address. If it is a privateIP address, which means there is an extra router/NAT in front of the TP-LINK router, and you have to open the same port as your server’s for TP-LINK router on that router/NAT.